# Initial Array of pointer to pointer in Delphi

Tags: delphi, pointers, hashtable

How can i Initial This Code?

```
type
  PPNode = ^PNode;
  PNode  = ^Node;
  CNode = array of PPNode;

  Node = record
    key: Integer;
    next: PNode;
    prev: PNode;
  end;
```

i use this way :

```
function TForm1.chained_hash_init(n: Integer): CNode;
var
  A: Cnode;
begin
  ...
  SetLength(A, N);
  Result := A;
  ...
end;
```

But I have Error in Memory For this access:

```
procedure TForm1.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  pcnArr: CNode;
begin    
  SetLength(pcnArr, 19);
  pcnArr := chained_hash_init(19);
  ShowMessage( IntToStr(pcnArr[i]^^.key)) );     // I have Problem Here :(     
end;
```

How Can I Initial Cnode ?

Comment: Sounds as if your local *var A: Cnode* is not properly set up, so you'll have to show more of what *chained_hash_init* does.

Comment: i don't know how to Initial Cnode.

Comment: Also what is `i` in your `TForm1.btn1Click` procedure. Is it a GLOBAL variable?

Comment: Gentlemen, I do believe OP means to say "initialize".

Comment: Problem Solved ( thanks valex ) but is there better implementation for this code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't initialized `pcnArr[i]` before ShowMesage. So you get "access violation" error.

So you should initialize `pcnArr` for example:

```
function TForm1.chained_hash_init(n: Integer): CNode;
var
  A: Cnode;
  i:integer;
  P:PNode;
begin
  ...
  SetLength(A, N);

  for i:=0 to N-1 do
  begin
    new(A[i]);
    new(A[i]^);
    with A[i]^^ do
    begin
        key:=0; 
        next:=nil; 
        prev:=nil; 
    end;  
  end;

  Result := A;
  ...
end;
```

Comment: Are you sure you can do A[i]^^? I haven't try it but it looks suspicious.

Comment: @mg30rg  `something^^` is ok but you can't do `^^someType`.  The former case can resolve the type at each step but the latter does not enforce a type in "the middle".

Comment: @J... Thanks, it is pretty good to know! I'm pretty new to Delphi (used to develop in C++ and C# for years, but recently moved to an enterprise which utilities Delphi), and I am in an endless doubt in pointer operations which seem to be a bit over-complicated.